# default value for the sqlite table columns, while inserting records

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite table with 25 columns, and first 10 columns i update in function_1, and and rest of the columns i update in the function_2 column.

But while updating i get the following error:

```
Error: table AirMode has 25 columns but 10 values were supplied.
```

Which clearly indicates that either there should be a way to tell rest of 15 columns should be passed with default value.

How to do without adding additional 15 columns in the same query with default value?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only supply the columns in your insert statement you want to fill

```
insert into your_table (col1, col2, ..., col10)
values ('1', '2', ..., '10')
```